# What is the difference between Adapter and AdapterView in Android?

Tags: android

Beginning Android development, i am having a big problem understanding how listviews and gridviews work and the adapters and their role

am very grateful for anyone who would help me,  that will be really a great favor for me.

Comment: Thanks very much for you all , i can now read the docs with more comprehension

Comment: Could you please accept an answer?

Answer (score 13):

An `Adapter` is responsible for creating and binding data to views. An `Adapter` isn't an actual view, but instead produces them.

An `AdapterView` is a ViewGroup that gets its child views from an `Adapter`.

E.g. a `ListView` has a child view for each row in its list. Those child views are created and bound with data by an `Adapter`.

Answer (score 5):

From the docs

[`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html):

> An Adapter object acts as a bridge between an AdapterView and the
>   underlying data for that view. The Adapter provides access to the data
>   items. The Adapter is also responsible for making a View for each item
>   in the data set.

[`AdapterView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html):

> An AdapterView is a view whose children are determined by an Adapter.

Answer (score 5):

All of the answers sum it up.  But I think of:

An AdapterView has an Adapter. An Adapter has Data.

ie. 
  AdapterView <-- Adapter <-- Data

Comment: Yes, AdapterView has an Adapter and an Adapter has data.But what is an Adapter,and what is an AdapterView? You didn't answer the question

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't yet read the docs I suggest you do. They are pretty clear on this general question.

[From the AdapterView Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html)

> An AdapterView is a view whose children are determined by an Adapter.

[From the Adapter Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)

> An Adapter object acts as a bridge between an AdapterView and the underlying data for that view.

So, basically you have the `View` which displays the data. The data comes from the `Adapter` and the `AdapterView` brings the data and the `View` together by displaying a list of the `View`s.

Answer (score 0):

An Adapter is the interface between a data source (array, database, network etc..), while an AdapterView is a ViewGroup which child views are generated from an Adapter (Spinners, ListViews for example)